# VB.net Fill Dataset at Application Start

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, dataset

I have a winforms application that has an sql server backend.  I have some tables that have static data, lookup tables, that I would like to fill in my dataset at application start to be used throughout the application when needed.

Normally in a form I would use something like this: Me.TEMSWBSETableAdapter.Fill(Me.EMS_DS.TEMSWBSE)

But I would have to do that in every form that required that data.  The problem is it takes awhile to load that data, so I would like to load the data at startup in a background worker that can be used by any form that requires it.  Basically filling the dataset with that data for use throughout.

I am not sure how to do this.  Can someone point me in the right direction.
Thanks

Comment: I think, this will depend on how long the loading of the DataTable will last. Maybe a spashscreen would be good (loading the data into a global DataTable).

Comment: right now i do use a splashscreen.  It takes 2-3 mins for the data to load.  Ill look up global datatables.

Comment: If you define your DataTable in a module, it should be globally available. 2-3 mins is a long time, maybe you can optimize your query. I'm not very firm with mssql, but mysql has got many queries that will run much faster if you write it in another way (some queries moved down from minutes to seconds).

Comment: It is just a table with a million records.  It is just a simple select statement, no way to optimize.

Comment: Looking into global datasets now.  Trying to find a good example.

Comment: Very hard to read, but I think, this will work.

Comment: I dont know how to format code in comments.

Comment: So is this correct:

    So is this correct:

Module dsglobal

    Public lookupds As EMS_DS

    Public Sub populateDS()
        lookupds = New EMS_DS

        Dim ta As New EMS_DSTableAdapters.TEMSWBSETableAdapter
        ta.Fill(lookupds.TEMSWBSE)

        Dim ta1 As New EMS_DSTableAdapters.TEMSCCTRTableAdapter
        ta1.Fill(lookupds.TEMSCCTR)
    End Sub

End Module

Comment: You are on the right track when you suggest loading a datatable using a backgroundworker or other multi-threading technique - although this may not even be necessary since it may well be that you can't really progress until your cache is loaded anyway, so you might as well wait for it. Show us what you have tried.
Incidentally, do you literally mean a million records or is that a figure of speech? A million records is not a huge number for a db, but it *is* a huge number for a lookup!

Comment: I pretty much did what i posted in my last comment.  Yes, it is like 1.4 million records and yes, big for a lookup, but nothing I can do for that.

Answer (score 0):

*you first need to implement DataReder object that can retrieve data with out creating a database TableAdapter. this will load your data with forward only and read only mode of the ADO.net mechanism.then you can implement ExecuteNonQuery() method to append the changes directly to the database.*